# Validate form if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a credit card project. And I have a function in javascript (`validateCreditCard`) that helps me validate the credit card and return the credit card type. After getting the credit card type, I store as value of the hidden input `cardType` to be used after submission of the form. after clicking on the submit button, the user is taken to 'proceed.php' if the function `cardFormValidate` returns `true`.

This is what I have being trying to realize by writing those lines of code but the value of the hidden input is still empty. Kindly help me.
Sorry I am not a native english speaker

```js
function cardFormValidate() {

        //Card validation
        var card_number = $('#CreditCardNumber');
        card_number.validateCreditCard(function (result) {
            var cardType = (result.card_type == null) ? '' : result.card_type.name;
            if (result.valid) {
                $("#cardType").val(cardType);
                cardValid = true;
            } else {
                $("#cardType").val('');
                cardValid = false;
            }
          return cardValid;
        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Submit card form
        $("#PayButton").on('click',function(){
            if (cardFormValidate()) {
                //Move to proceed.php to treat the form
            }else{
              alert('bad credit card');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<form method="post" action="proceed.php">
    <input name="cardType" type="hidden" id="cardType">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="NameOnCard">Name on card</label>
        <label for="NameOnCard"></label><input id="NameOnCard" class="form-control" type="text" name="NameOnCard" maxlength="255"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CreditCardNumber">Card number</label>
        <input id="CreditCardNumber" class="null card-image form-control" name="CreditCardNumber" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <button id="PayButton" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your JS function is not executing `else {
                $("#cardType").val('');
                cardValid = false;
            }` else part ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `validateCreditCard` function is not executing properly  and you are getting null value ..

1 ) first check Are You getting `Card_Number`??

put `alert(card_number)` if not then 
try this line

```
var card_number = $('#CreditCardNumber').val();
```

2) return data of  `validateCreditCard`   must have `name` property check it out otherwise you will get null value..